# Rounded corners effect not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to give a rounded corners effect to the buttons on my ASP.NET website using CSS by using the CSS and .js script from here.

http://www.monc.se/kitchen/59/scalable-css-buttons-using-png-and-background-colors

I just need to reference the buttons with the class. For eg:

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/btns.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" media="screen" title="ie6" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="switch.js"></script>
</head>
    -----Body---
     <a href="" class="btn green">Test </a>
```

But the above is not giving me the rounded corners effect through it is applying the green color property and the hover color from the CSS but the main thing I wanted was the corners effect. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

That should work in most browsers.

Comment: Border-Radius is not a known CSS property name

Comment: @Cipher, that's because border-radius is a CSS3 style. The above will add rounded corners in every modern browser (IE is not a modern browser).

Answer (score 1):

It's CSS3 time.
Try this: [CSS Rounded Corners In All Browsers (With No Images)](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used/copied the image http://www.monc.se/kitchen/stew/buttons/btn2.png also. This image is what gives the round corner effect.

Comment: Try using Firebug..Also if you provide a version of the HTML you have using jsfiddle.net it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that not all browsers support rounded corners as they are relatively new. As Sam points out, some browsers have been using non-standard rounded-corner terms until the behavior of border-radius has been fully standardized.

This is still a new technique and it will be a while before all users will be using browsers that support it.

What browser are you using?

Comment: For the time being, I was testing this on Firefox 3.6.13 although I cannot neglect IE for the site.

Comment: IE is extremely vague as it could refer to IE6, IE7, IE8, or IE9, which are all very different. Of the four, only IE9 would provide substantial support for rounded corners. I personally use Chrome and it seems to support rounded corners. I'm not at my development machine but think Firefox should support this.